# PHP exec returns status 1 but empty array

Tags: java, php

I am trying to execute a Java program from a PHP code and get the output back to the PHP code.

This is the simple code:

`Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Then I compile the `Main.java` file using the `javac Main.java` command, and it creates a class file `Main.class`

Then I execute it from the PHP script:

`index.php`:

```
<?php
$output=null;
$retval=null;
exec('java Main', $output, $retval);
echo "Returned with status $retval and output:\n";
print_r($output);
```

But the output is `Returned with status 1 and output: Array ( )`

Comment: Is the `Main` class inside a package or something?

Comment: Nope it's just a file I created in the root of the project folder (I have the Java folder in the System PATH variable)

Comment: Did you try executing with the full path? e.g. `exec('java /full/path/to/Main', $output, $retval);`

Comment: The command is undoubtedly trying to tell you what's wrong. Use `'java Main 2>&1'` to show the error log when it fails

Comment: I also recommend you find the full path to your java executable (`which java`). PHP's exec function doesn't always know where this is located. On *nix systems it can be in `/usr/bin/java` in which case you can do `exec('/usr/bin/java /full/path/to/Main', $output, $retval);`

Comment: Thank you guys! @thatotherguy yes! I thought that if I added the Java bin folder to the System PATH variable (on Windows), then the PHP script would know what `java` is, but apparently it's not the case. Now with the full path it's working. By the way, I did not need to run `javac` to compile it before, I simply used `java.exe` and it worked, and actually did not work if I compile it. So why some places show you need to compile it and then run the Class it creates?

Comment: You need to compile and run with the correct classpath if: the program is split between multiple .java files, or if you are running on a JDK < 11 (before JEP330). If you only have a single .java file on 11+, then you can run `java /path/to/yourfile.java` and not have to ensure the classpath is correct.

Comment: @thatotherguy  thank you that other guy with plenty of knowledge. May I ask you one more thing: Is it possible to also send params from the PHP script to the Java program if it's on the same PC? Or I will have to use something like a database. (I need to send params to the Java program, then get the result back, then use that result to update the params and send back to the Java program and so on)

Comment: There are various ways. For example, you can run `java YourFile arg1 arg2` and read them from the `String[] args` in the Java program's main method. To return data, you can use `System.out` and get it from your PHP script's `$output` variable

Comment: Wow! I just used `exec('C:\Java\jdk-18\bin\java.exe Main.java 2>&1 ' . $arg1 . ' ' . $arg2, $output, $retval);` and it worked! Thank you again!